# Retrieve organization name from email address with Auth0

Tags: java, auth0

Is it possible when user signs up to my application with Auth0 that I can get the organization name of the email address that it belongs to? If so, how can we do it?

Comment: Hi there. Please provide us with what you've already tried! [ask]

Comment: maybe add an example to express your question more clearly